# Create Postgresql Extension for Multiple Schema

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema, postgis

I Work with Postgresql 9.2 and I try to make Postgis 2.x extension for two schemas

My code is

```
create extension postgis schema public
```

it is working but I want to create extension for two schemas   e.g public,second ...

Can anibody help me?

Comment: Specifying a schema while creating an extension indicates where you want the extension's objects created, not for which schemas the extension is available - it's available for the whole DB.

Comment: There is no db option
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createextension.html

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createextension.html

Extension itself is not considered to be within any schema, but it can save objects within specified schema. Specifying more than one schema is an unrealizable.